# Trouble assigning instance in C++ array with malloc

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc, ffi

This seems so basic I'm having difficulty wording it. I'm wrapping C++ with C and calling the C from another language, so do bear with the non-idiomatic C++. That said, if there is a better way to do things, I'm all ears.

I would have thought this was a good way to make an array of `xla::Shape`s

```
xla::Shape* arr = (xla::Shape*) malloc(2 * sizeof(xla::Shape));
arr[0] = xla::Shape();
```

but I'm getting undefined behaviour: hangs and a selection of errors.

In my actual setup, `arr` is constructed via a call to `malloc` from the third language's stdlib through FFI. The `xla::Shape()` is also passed as a value through FFI.

Comment: The code creates a blob of uninitialized memory then uses the assignment operator. Assignment assumes that an object already exists.

Comment: no, `arr` si NOT constructed via `malloc`... `malloc` does not call the constructor, `malloc` returns a pointer to an allocated memory block, that's all.

Comment: @PeteBecker does that mean there is no way to write the contents of `xla::Shape()` to the first half of `arr`?

Comment: std::construct_at

Comment: @Sedenion i'm not quite following. I understand that `malloc` just allocates memory, and doesn't create any `xla::Shape`s, but I get the impression you mean I need another step to be able to do what i want

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow thanks, though needing a feature from C++20 makes me suspect I'm looking at this wrong

Comment: The old way is placement new: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: @joel `std::construct_at(arr + i, /* construct args */)` just is a nicer function form around what would simply be `new(arr + i) xla::Shape(/* constructor args */)` here or for a more general version taking care of some edge cases, see the "equivalent to" at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at.

Comment: @user17732522 and is there a way to do that with a pre-existing `xla::Shape` that's accessible as an argument of the enclosing function?

Comment: If you pass the pre-existing object to placement `new`, you will invoke copy constructor (or move constructor if you move that object).

Comment: Also note that the memory returned by malloc potentially isn't properly aligned. You should use `std::aligned_alloc()` instead of malloc. Or use new: `xla::Shape *arr = static_cast<xla::Shape*>(operator new[](sizeof(xla::Shape) * 2, static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(xla::Shape))));`. But seriously, why not use `new xla::Shape[2];`? That's perfectly fine for use with C.

Comment: @joel Just pass it as constructor argument and it will use the copy constructor to construct the new `xla::Shape`. Beware that if you use this approach, you will also need to manually call the destructors of all elements before `free`ing the memory. If you don't have a very good reason to do any of this, simply use `new`/`delete` instead or even better `std::vector` (though I can see the interoperability issue with the latter).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Or you can move from it, yes?

Comment: @PaulSanders Sure. I wasn't sure if OP can use C++11, given that "non-idiomatic C++" and the fact that they didn't want C++20 features. Managed to edit my comment in time c:

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i'm using C++14 i believe

Comment: Concerning terminology: “undefined behavior” is a property of source code. The behavior of the code in the question is undefined; the C++ standard doesn’t tell you what it does. The behavior described in the question is a symptom of that undefined behavior.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow this is the second time today I've seen someone directly call `operator new[](...)` with verbose size and alignment parameters, instead of simply using a standard `new[]` expression, what is up with that? Yes, just use `xla::Shape *arr = new xla::Shape[2];` instead. The memory will be properly sized and aligned.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The original code was doing it manually in 2 steps: 1) get unintialized memory for 2 objects, 2) call the constructor for the first. That `new[]` call just replicates that. The `new xla::Shape[2]` will initialize both objects.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow except that when `arr` is pointing at *uninitialized* memory, `arr[index] = xla::Shape();` is *undefined behavior*, as it constructs a new object and then assigns it to an *invalid* object. One would need to use `new(arr+index) xla::Shape();` or `std::construct_at(arr+index);` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, as already mentioned in the comments earlier.